# K-means cluster - Plot class proportions in each cluster

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I am working on a project where I exploit the cluster structure of an unlabeled dataset to improve the performance of a supervised learning clustering algorithm. After preprocessing the data - stored in a matrix - I use k-means to cluster the data like so:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
k = KMeans(n_clusters=40).fit(X)
```

I have the desired labels stored in `y`. I am intrested in seeing how the different classes are clustered ie. if the clusters are relatively pure or mixed.

To do this I want to see the proportions of each class in each cluster. This is a binary classification task - positive (represented by a 1 in y) instances and negative instances (represented by a 0 in y ).

(The nth element of the y array is the correct label for the nth row of the X matrix.)

Comment: What is _positive_ and _negative_ instances?

Comment: @DYZ Have edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Combine the true labels and cluster labels into a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'clusters' : k.labels_, 'labels' : y})
```

Group by clusters and for each cluster get the fraction of 1's:

```
df.groupby('clusters').apply(lambda cluster: cluster.sum()/cluster.count())
```